# Installing PHP extensions not showing in environment

Tags: php, unix, apt

I wasn't sure whether to include this in Ask Ubuntu or Stack Overflow where I decided on Stack Overflow since I'm having some parsing issues.

**Using Ubuntu 17.04, PHP5.6 in XAMPP**

So I'm trying to use the **bitwasp/bitcoin** composer package and it requires two extensions to be installed, `ext-gmp` and `ext-bcmath`, where I have installed them using:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-bcmath
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gmp
```

When executing the Bitcoin code, I get this error:

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function Mdanter\Ecc\Curves\gmp_init() in **/usr/dev/proj/PROECTNAME/vendor/mdanter/ecc/src/Curves/SecgCurve.php** on line **117**

Bcmath has successfully been found, but gmp hasn't. (using `/opt/lampp/bin/php -m` it's not on the list)

By running `sudo apt-get install php5.6-gmp` I get:

[image: image of terminal text]

Here is a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/1ideSzzw) of the PHP modules I have concerning `/opt/lampp/php -m`.

Things I've tried:

- Purge packages then re-install using different versions, but the default `php-gmp` package is for PHP7
- Adding `extension=gmp`, `=php_gmp.so`, `=gmp.so`, gives me an error that the extension was not able to be found.

Comment: Can you show us what it returns in the terminal when you run `sudo apt-get install php5.6-gmp`?

Comment: @ChinLeung done :)

Comment: Whats the output of `ls -lr /etc/php*` ?

Comment: I elaborated on it by going into `/etc/php/5.6/mods-available` and found that there is a `gmp.ini` file that I opened and found `extension=gmp.so` inside of it. @AlexKapustin